# Google Cloud SQL Postgres, when will PG 10 be available?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, postgresql-10

I am planning on moving our main project to Postgres 10 at some point.  I like to keep the local dev's database version close to what we are running on prod.

Currently our prod database is on Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL 9.6.  I have not heard anything from Google on when this managed cloud sql product will offer Postgres 10.x in addition to 9.6.

Does anyone know when Postgres 10 will be a supported option on GCP's managed SQL product?  I would like to start planning for it.

Comment: What did Google say when you asked them? I doubt the stackoverflow community will have better information than the company involved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very localized to one point in time.

Answer (score 11):

There is not much information about it publicly, no ETA or whatsoever.

This very same issue was already raised in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71565188), so it's worth to check it out.

Your only options right now would be keeping using 9.6 or manage your own installation on Compute Engine, but I understand neither options are pleasant.

**EDIT**:
As of April 9, 2019, PostgreSQL 11.1 is supported [on beta](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/release-notes?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks, that issue tracker is just what I was looking for.

Comment: PG 11 seems now available !

Answer (score 5):

Cloud SQL now supports PostgreSQL version 11.1 in beta [[link]](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/release-notes?hl=en).

**Previous answer:**

According to this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71565188#comment73) answer, Cloud SQL support for PostgreSQL 10 and 11 is under active development and is likely to be available in the second quarter of 2019.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/release-notes), PostgreSQL 11 just became publicly available for Cloud SQL instances.

Answer (score 0):

As of September 27, 2019, PostgreSQL version 11 is generally available and is the default version in Google Cloud SQL.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/release-notes#september_27_2019